# Angular Basic Factory Binding not updating Controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm trying to create an SPA website where I have multiple controllers that depend on an AuthService, this service is just in charge of telling all the controllers if the User is signedIn and who the user is. AFAIK since all the controllers share the same service object, the changes should propagate to them, but so far this is not happening.

My code goes as follows:

I have a NavbarController and a LoginController. The NavbarController is in charge of displaying the Login/Logout links depending on the Logged property of the AuthService. The LoginController is in charge of the login panel and calling   the login on the server through the AuthService.

> AuthService

```
(function () {
    var auth = angular.module('Auth', []);
    auth.factory('AuthService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.User = {};
        obj.Logged = true;

        obj.GetUser = function () {
            $http.get('api/Account/UserDetails')
            .success(function (data) {
                obj.User = data;
                obj.Logged = true;
            })
        }

        obj.Login = function (data) {
            var func = $http.post('api/Account/Login', data);
            func.success(function (data) {
                if (data.StatusCode == 200) {
                    obj.GetUser();
                }
            });
            return func;
        }

        obj.Logoff = function () {
            $http.get('api/Account/Logoff')
                .success(function () {
                    obj.User = {};
                    obj.Logged = false;
                });
        }
        return obj;
    }]);
})();
```

> LoginController

```
(function () {
    var login = angular.module('Login', ['LoginService','Auth']);

    login.controller('LoginController', ['accountService','AuthService', function (accountService,authService) {
        this.OnFocus = function(obj)
        {
            $(obj.target).closest(".textbox-wrap").addClass("focused");
        }

        this.OnBlur = function(obj)
        {
            $(obj.target).closest(".textbox-wrap").removeClass("focused");
        }

        this.loginCredentials = {};

        this.Login = function () {
            authService.Login(this.loginCredentials)
                .success(function (data) {
                    alert(data.StatusCode);
                })
                .error(function () {
                    alert("error");
                });
        }

    }]);

    login.directive('hcCheckbox', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                element.iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
                    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
                });
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

> NavbarController

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('main');
    app.controller('NavbarController', ['AuthService', function (AuthService) {
        var self = this;
        self.Logged = AuthService.Logged;
        self.User = AuthService.User;
        self.Logoff = function()
        {
            AuthService.Logoff();
        }

    }]);
})();
```

> Navbar html template

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="NavbarController as NavbarCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navegacion">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HACSYS</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navegacion">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Details</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ng-hide="NavbarCtrl.Logged">
                    <a href="#/Login"> Login</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-show="NavbarCtrl.Logged">
                    <a ng-click="NavbarCtrl.Logoff()" href=""> Logoff</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I know I could use $watch to propagate changes to other controllers, but this way seems cleaner to me, I have seen other examples where this works, and I still can't figure out whats going wrong with my code

Comment: I think you need to change your object structure which store use data, it could be `var obj = {}; obj = {data: { User : {}, Logged: true }}`

Comment: Either that or use a function to return the logged value.  I'm sure that you're user object (which is by ref) is changing, but only the primitive no reference Logged isn't changing (since it isn't a reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to ensure that changes are propagated correctly across all the nested scopes, you need to bind to an object by reference. If you bind to a primitive, it creates a copy of the value on scope, effectively breaking the linkage between the scope variables.  To resolve this, bind by reference:

```
app.controller('NavbarController', ['AuthService', '$scope', function (AuthService, $scope) {
    var self = this;        
    $scope.AuthService = AuthService;
    self.Logoff = function()
    {
        $scope.AuthService.Logoff();
    }
}]);
```

When you bind by reference, any controller where you inject AuthService will bind and propagate as expected.

```
app.controller('otherController', function($scope, AuthService) {
      $scope.AuthService = AuthService;
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="otherController">
   <div ng-show="AuthService.Logged">
       User is logged in!
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested:
(https://jsfiddle.net/suuo9wp5/)
The $scope.AuthService changes accordingly, but the other properties do not. I can understand why the Logged property isnt getting updated, but what about the user object
(Moved the code to a jsfiddle for better readeability)